# How to obtain WGS84 or Projected Bounds for given EPSG in postgis?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

On the http://spatialreference.org, for almost all SRS are definied WGS84 Bounds and Projected Bounds.

How to obtain this bounds from postgis? Spatial_ref_sys does not contains this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to download the EPSG database and pull the information you want from it. They do provide PostgreSQL-compatible downloads. http://www.epsg.org/DownloadDataset