# Is there a PostGIS function for checking the validity of a lon/lat pair, given a coordinate system?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I have data with lon lat pairs that I'm converting to geography types. Some of the pairs, however, are corrupt -- in my case, very negative values for longitude.

Is there a helper function in postgis that I can use to exclude such pairs? I'd like to exclude rows whose lon lat values aren't valid given the range of my coordinate system.

I'd like to do something like:

```
select *
from data_with_lonlats
where POINT_IS_VALID(ST_POINT(longitude, latitude), 4326)
```

where `4326` is my coordinate system, which has range `[-180 -90, 180 90]`.

Comment: As you know the crs range why not something "(longitude BETWEEN -180 AND 180) AND (latitude BETWEEN -90 AND 90)"

Comment: You would use your lat & lon as the rule and exclude lat & lon that weren't true to the rule. So, Select * from table where lat between # and  # AND Lon between # and #

Comment: I could! haha. i'm wondering if there's something built-in. It seems like there is... when i try to make a geography for the point, postgres warns that it's coercing the value to fit in the range. is that process using a helper function to check if it needs to coerce the value? if so, can i use it?

Comment: i'd also be interested in something that does this for polygons... and the `between` logic isn't useful there

Comment: PostGIS [does not know coordinate system bounds](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152913/how-to-obtain-wgs84-or-projected-bounds-for-given-epsg-in-postgis).

Comment: @CL. if postgis doesn't know coordinate bounds, how does it know to coerce values to be within the required bounds?

Comment: @grisaitis Most mathematical transformations do not work for all points on the Earth's surface, so PostGIS has to move some points into the theoretical bounds. However, those are not practical bounds; coordinate system have smaller bounds to avoid regions where the distiortions become too large, and "too large" is subjective, so the software cannot know them just from the projection formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_valid_geography(geometry) RETURNS boolean AS
  'SELECT ST_XMin($1) >= -180 AND ST_XMax($1) <= 180 AND
          ST_YMin($1) >= -90 AND ST_YMax($1) <= 90;'
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

It should work on any type of geometry.

Comment: thanks - accepting as correct, unless/until someone identifies a built in function